# Altium Designer - 45 degree rotation

Tags: altium

I am using Altium designer 15.

How can you rotate a component by 45 degree in PCB mode?

Regards,
MathieuL

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I know that there are a few ways of doing it, but this is the way I use (because I can't remember the other way and it wasn't important enough for me to find out).

Go to your preferences
PCB editor
Under the "Other" section, change rotation step to 45deg.

Comment: +1 Or just select the component properties (right-click) and type in 45 or -45 for "Rotation". Or any other angle that suits your fancy.

Comment: It is available to rotate multiple (or single) components with Edit --> Move --> Rotate Selection, add angle then left-click.